# Lightning Component Cache Issue where URL visible and decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)) gives different output

Tags: lightning-aura-components, url, cache

The url of the lightning component that i could see is like "/lightning/cmp/c__LCMP_AddLeadLine?c__leadId=00Q1g000004qAR5"

But "component.get("v.pageReference").state.c__leadId" gives the output as "00Q1g000004HUEe"
And "decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1))" gives the output as "c__leadId=00Q1g000004HUEe"

The ids are changing based the the previous lead opened. Looks like a cache or some wierd salesforce issue. I have even tried disabling 'Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance' in session settings and still the issue persists.

Can some one please help me here.

Comment: can  you share your code where and how are you using it?

Comment: I'm using a url button to redirect to a lightning component which has been implemented using lightning:isUrlAddressable.

The url button to redirect on lead is as : /lightning/cmp/c__componentName?c__leadId={!Lead.Id}

And in the init method im trying to get the leadId using component.get("v.pageReference").state.c__leadId

Comment: you can try using this <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> in action whatever method you have which run during initialization

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its works on adding the line you mentioned.